# Treat relation as a list of strings

Tags: sqlalchemy

```py
class User:
    id = Column(String(), primary_key=True)
    favorite_names = relationship("FavoriteName")

class FavoriteName:
    user_id = Column(
        String(), 
        ForeignKey("user.id", onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        primary_key=True
    )
    name = Column(String(), primary_key=True)
```

In an example like above, is it possible to treat `User.favorite_names` as a `list` of `str` values (representing the `FavoriteName.name` property) rather than a `list` of `FavoriteName` instances?

I'm hoping I would be able to do something like:

```py
myUser = session.query(User).one()
myUser.favorite_names.append("Samantha")
session.commit()
```

Comment: This example in using `association_proxy` does just that: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-scalar-collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SuperShoot mentioned in a comment on my question, I'm describing an [`association_proxy`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-scalar-collections).